# need to open popup window behind page

Tags: javascript, popup

**Here is my code**

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
var popunder
function get_cookie(Name) {
var search = Name + "="
var returnvalue = "";
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
offset += search.length
// set index of beginning of value
end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
// set index of end of cookie value
if (end == -1)
end = document.cookie.length;
returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
}
}
return returnvalue;
}
popfrequency="0 minutes"
function resetcookie(){
var expireDate = new Date()
expireDate.setMinutes(expireDate.getMinutes()-0)
document.cookie = "popunder=;path=/;expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
}
function loadornot(){
if (get_cookie('popunder')==''){
loadpopunder()
var expireDate = new Date()
expireDate.setMinutes(expireDate.getMinutes()+parseInt(popfrequency))
document.cookie = "popunder="+parseInt(popfrequency)+";path=/;expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
}
}
function loadpopunder(){
document.write('<body onclick="rwmrgfdq_Popup()" >');
}
if (get_cookie('popunder')!=parseInt(popfrequency))
resetcookie()
loadornot()

</script>   <script type="text/javascript"> <!--
var opened;
function rwmrgfdq_Popup()
{
if(opened != 1)
{
opened = 1;
window.open("http://www.masrawy.com", "rwmrgfdqpop", "scrollbars = 1, resizable = 1,status = 1 ");


}
}
//--> </script>
```

Comment: You didn't mention your problem

Comment: wouldn't .focus() on the main window push the popup to the background?

Comment: .focus(); dosnt work !! and where i put it exactly !

Comment: Even better: don't push a popup window to the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke `window.focus()` after `window.open()` in `rwmrgfdq_Popup()`